# Android Zooming functionality using Scaling operation lags(not smooth) on High Pixel density devices

Tags: android, scaling, screen-resolution, zooming

i am working on this android project, which has this typical UI like 3D chess board grid. Which has Zoom Pan/drag feature on this screen.
I have implemented this functionality by creating custom frame layout class. 
Snippet :

```
public class ZoomLayout extends FrameLayout implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {
    float x1=0,y1=0,x2,y2;
    ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;
    Context mContext;

    private enum Mode {
        NONE,
        DRAG,
        ZOOM
    }

    private static final String TAG = "ZoomLayout";
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
    private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 6.0f;

    private Mode mode = Mode.NONE;
    private float scale = 1.0f;
    private float lastScaleFactor = 0f;

    // Where the finger first  touches the screen
    private float startX = 0f;
    private float startY = 0f;

    // How much to translate the canvas
    private float dx = 0f;
    private float dy = 0f;
    private float prevDx = 0f;
    private float prevDy = 0f;

    ApiCommunicationListener apiListener;
    Activity mActivity;

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, ApiCommunicationListener apiListener, Activity activity) {
        super(context);
        this.apiListener = apiListener;
        this.mActivity = activity;
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public ZoomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
 }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
 switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = motionEvent.getX();
                y1 = motionEvent.getY();

                // System.out.println("TOUCH DOWN : X:" + x1 + " Y:" + y1);

                if (scale > MIN_ZOOM) {
                    mode = Mode.DRAG;
                    startX = motionEvent.getX() - prevDx;
                    startY = motionEvent.getY() - prevDy;
                }

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == Mode.DRAG) {
                    dx = motionEvent.getX() - startX;
                    dy = motionEvent.getY() - startY;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                mode = Mode.ZOOM;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                //mode = Mode.DRAG;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = motionEvent.getX();
                y2 = motionEvent.getY();
                // System.out.println("TOUCH UP : X:" + x2 + " Y:" + y2);
                mode = Mode.NONE;
                prevDx = dx;
                prevDy = dy;

                if (x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 && ApocketApp.mViewClicked != null) {
                    Utilities.sysOut("-------------In ZoomLayout");

                    if (ApocketApp.mViewClicked.getTag().toString().contains("A"))
                        apiListener.onSuccess("onAvatarClick");
                    else
                        apiListener.onSuccess("onBuildingClick");
                }

                break;
        }
        scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);

        if ((mode == Mode.DRAG && scale >= MIN_ZOOM) || mode == Mode.ZOOM) {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            float maxDx = (child().getWidth() - (child().getWidth() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
            float maxDy = (child().getHeight() - (child().getHeight() / scale)) / 2 * scale;
            dx = Math.min(Math.max(dx, -maxDx), maxDx);
            dy = Math.min(Math.max(dy, -maxDy), maxDy);
            /*Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + child().getWidth() + ", scale " + scale + ", dx " + dx
                    + ", max " + maxDx);*/
            applyScaleAndTranslation();
        }

        return true;
    }
  @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        // Log.i(TAG, "onScaleBegin");
       // setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        float scaleFactor = scaleDetector.getScaleFactor();
        //Log.i(TAG, "onScale" + scaleFactor);

        if (lastScaleFactor == 0 || (Math.signum(scaleFactor) == Math.signum(lastScaleFactor))) {
            scale *= scaleFactor;
            scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));
            lastScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        } else {
            lastScaleFactor = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "onScaleEnd");
       // setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    }

    private void applyScaleAndTranslation() {
        child().setScaleX(scale);
        child().setScaleY(scale);
        child().setTranslationX(dx);
        child().setTranslationY(dy);
    }

    private View child() {
        return getChildAt(0);
    }

    public void animateToCentre(final RelativeLayout relativeLayout){
 Resources res  = mContext.getResources();
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        res.getValue(R.dimen.zoom_centre_level_max, outValue, true);
        final float zoomEnd = outValue.getFloat();
        ObjectAnimator oaX = new ObjectAnimator();
        oaX.setDuration(res.getInteger(R.integer.zoom_centre_duration));
        oaX.setFloatValues(new float[]{1.0f, zoomEnd});
        oaX.setPropertyName("scaleX");
        oaX.setFrameDelay(10);
        ObjectAnimator oaY = new ObjectAnimator();
        oaY.setDuration(res.getInteger(R.integer.zoom_centre_duration));
        oaY.setFloatValues(new float[]{1.0f, zoomEnd});
        oaY.setPropertyName("scaleY");
        oaY.setFrameDelay(10);
        ObjectAnimator oaTy = new ObjectAnimator();
        oaTy.setDuration(res.getInteger(R.integer.zoom_centre_duration));
        oaTy.setFloatValues(new float[]{0.0f, res.getDimension(R.dimen.v_5) * 3});
        oaTy.setPropertyName("translationY");
        oaTy.setFrameDelay(10);

        AnimatorSet zoomAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
        zoomAnimation.playTogether(new ObjectAnimator[]{oaX, oaY, oaTy});
        //AnimatorSet zoomAnimation = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(mContext, R.anim.zoom_in_out);
        zoomAnimation.setTarget(child());
        zoomAnimation.setInterpolator(new FastOutLinearInInterpolator());
        zoomAnimation.start();
        zoomAnimation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                //setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
                scale = zoomEnd;
 }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

The zooming works fine,smoothly on hdpi or xhdpi devices but it lags on xxhdpi and xxxhdpi devices.Hi have tried using HardwareAccelaration = true in manifest, but doesn't make much difference. 
So please can any body suggest some approach to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No answers yet,.. does nobuddy had ever face this issue. OMG